# WPF why are all row heights expanding when last row is *

Tags: wpf

I have a form with several columns and rows defined as follows:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="280" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then I have a StackPanel which spans columns and rows:

```
<StackPanel Name="foo" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="7"></StackPanel>
```

When StackPanel "foo" contains items which cause the total height to be more than all the rows combined, I want only the last row height to expand.  Instead, all the row heights are expanding equally, creating a lot of space between the controls.

Before "foo" is filled with data:
[image]

After "foo" is filled with data:
[image]

How can I code this so that only that last row with height="*" expands, and the other row heights stay the same?

Comment: you do not want to expand controls that are located in `RowDefinition Height=*` of your `StackPanel`?

Comment: Try with `Height="auto"`. Or specify a `MaxHeight`, instead of `Height`

Comment: @StepUp yes I want to expand ONLY the row with Height="*" but all the row heights are expanding equally.  The control which is expanding spans several rows.

Comment: @Kirenenko using `Height="Auto"` or using `MaxHeight` gives the same result.

Comment: Can you post the header of your grid?

Comment: am I right that you do not want to expand the last `RowDefinition` at the `StackPanel`?

Comment: @Kirenenko`<Grid MinWidth="800" MinHeight="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">`

Comment: @StepUp yes I want to expand ONLY the last row with Height="*", not all the other rows.  I added screen shots to show what is happening.

Comment: The StackPanel reaches from the third to the seventh row, so it sizes allong with the *. The items within the StackPanel only regard for their parents size, so they do not know about any RowDefninitions. Show us how you have setup the editable fields.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this until I added a `StackPanel` around that grid. I then tried setting a fixed `Height` on the grid and that resulted in normal, expected behavior again. Changing the row heights from fixed heights to `Auto` works as expected, too. This looks like a layouting issue in the `Grid` class to me.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet this grid is wrapped in a `ScrollViewer` so maybe that's significant.  Thanks for your time in reproducing the issue.

Comment: just show all your XAML. It helps to you to move along more quickly.

Comment: @StepUp if I posted all the XAML in this example no one would bother to read the question :-)  I tried to keep it readable by posting what I thought was the relevant code only.  I should have included the `ScrollViewer` though

Comment: it is not enough. Where are your controls?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a solution, but what I ended up doing was to remove the `ScrollViewer` which wrapped around my grid, and wrapped the `StackPanel` with a `ScrollViewer` instead.  This prevented the `StackPanel` from expanding the grid.